# A Form's key events go missing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keyevent

I have a bug in my application that I don't know how to how to attack. Basically, key events "go missing" after some time. I have added event handlers to KeyDown, KeyPressed and KeyUp that write to the console (both for the Form and one of its TextBoxes). Here's the correct order of things:

```
control_PreviewKeyDown
ShellForm_KeyDown
control_KeyDown
ShellForm_KeyPress
control_KeyPress
ShellForm_KeyUp
control_KeyUp
```

In the failed state (which I can't reproduce consistently), I get these events when pressing a key (TextBox has focus):

```
ShellForm_KeyUp
control_KeyUp
```

Form.KeyPreview is true.

It's the same for all TextBoxes in the Form; they are not disabled and not set to readonly, but it's no longer possible to write text.

Problem is, I don't really know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin with `Application.AddMessageFilter(...)` just to intercept the flow of events.
You can find some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078366/c-sharp-system-windows-forms-keys-how-to-keep-application-hotkeys-in-one-pla).